# ghc-mod only shows first line in *GHC info*

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghc-mod

I am using **emacs** (24.3.1) in haskell-mode together with ghc-mod to play with Haskell.
Now everything works fine aside from one annoying thing:

Every output in the *GHC info* buffer contains only the first line.

For example when I ask for `ghc-show-info` (let's say on `sqlSettings` from *persist*) I get this:

[image]

while *Interactive-Haskell* works fine:

[image]

This happens with everything: infos, errors, warnings, etc.

Right now I have no clue what is causing this issue as it seems that ghc-mod in emacs is parsing the output wrong.

Maybe someone can help me get all the *info*.

Thanks

PS: maybe this one shows the problem a bit better:

[image]

instead of

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me? Probably you can post it as an issue in the bug tracker and see if any responses come. (I have the same experience with haskell-mode)

Comment: Pierre was right - ghc-mod 4.1.6 together with the emacs-package for this version did fix it again - maybe I had two versions mixed together on my system as I recently switched to the new haskell-plattform and reseted my haskell-env but I did not check all the emacs packages for new ones - seems I forgot ghc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be this bug https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/297

It has been fixed recently with ghc-mod >= 4.1.6

Comment: I have ghc-mod 4.1.6 running here (maybe I should have said so) - on the other hand maybe the .el from melpa is to old ... will check this - the bug tracker indeed seems like something similar

Comment: Indeed - that was the problem - I reinstalled the emacs-ghc package (I guess I forgot - the update was from Aug-19 - and voila - It works again